# How to lazy load css background images in vue.js 3 and quasar?

Tags: css, vuejs3, quasar-framework

when i add images in my quasar app i use the [q-img](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/img#introduction) component which uses lazy loading to load the images when the user scrolls to them like this:

```html
<q-img
      src="https://placeimg.com/500/300/nature"
      loading="lazy"
      spinner-color="white"
      height="140px"
      style="max-width: 150px"
/>
```

This reduces the initial page loading time, only loads the images when the user needs to view them and allows me to add high quality images without worrying about the app being slow.

However i cannot do this in the background images as i add the background images in css like this:

```css
.landing-section {
  height: 37rem;
  background: url("/images/home/landing-section/landing-img.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 20%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Background images allow you to stack images above each other and easily add content above them without the need to use things like `absolute` css property or the `grid`.

Is there a way to lazy load background images when they come to view (the user scrolls to them) ?

If not, is there a way to lazy load components in the same page when they come to viewport ?

Answer (score 0):

To know when a component comes into the viewport, Quasar provides the [Intersection component](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/intersection).

It provides a `@visibility` event on which you can trigger whatever you want